# How can I link to a slide within a frame that has allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer

How can you link to a specific slide within a frame that has `allowframebreaks` activated? So I have a frame that spans several slides. I would like to link at the end of the document to let's say the second slide of that frame. How is it possible in beamer? I know with `label`, I can link to the first slide, but not the second or third etc. I will try to make a MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor= pdftex, dvipsnames, table, 10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] 
Here must be content to fill at least 2 slides...
We can try Lipsum:
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Here should be the link the the second slide of the previous long frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried \hypertarget and \hyperlink?  \label links to the preceeding \refstepcounter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Ok that actually works. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you turn your comment into a response?

Comment: @AndréC - I'm not entirely sure where he wants the link to go, other than on page 2.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Since he didn't specify anything, made to your convenience, I'm very interested in your detailed answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses hypertarget and hyperlink.

```
\documentclass[xcolor, pdftex, dvipsnames, table, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] 
Here must be content to fill at least 2 slides...
We can try Lipsum:

\lipsum[1-2]

\hypertarget{linkname}{Here is a link target on the second page}

\lipsum[3-10]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{linkname}{Here} should be the link the the second slide of the previous long frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply!